# “Android is upgrading… Starting Apps” on boot

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, boot-loop, reboot

My phone is still stuck on "Android is upgrading.. starting apps" on boot.

Earlier, my phone said "Unfortunately, Google Playstore stopped working" and I am unable to use my apps which needed Internet access so I turned off my phone and removed my sd card before doing a factory reset. The reset was successful however it's been booting for several minutes already. I tried removing the battery and putting it back on. I rebooted the device and it is now stuck on "Android is upgrading.. starting apps." I tried removing the battery again and started wiping cache partition, doing factory reset again and rebooting the system but the problem is still the same.

Comment: How long have you left it? This step can take a very long time (i've seen it take over 15 minutes). It depends on the device and how many apps it needs to process. I'd suggest leaving it longer and seeing if it eventually finishes.

Answer (score -3):

Olá (hi)

You can recovery you device by installing again its original stock rom.

See more about it at the following website: (it is in portuguese)

http://smartmundo.com/brick-matar-aparelho/

Comment: There's no reason to think the questioner reads Portuguese, so perhaps instead of posting a useless link, you could summarise the content here in English. Link-only answers - even to English-language sites - are discouraged here because they become completely useless if the linked content goes away.